# $\mathbb R -\mathbb Q$ is not a linear continuum

Tags: general-topology

"$\mathbb R -\mathbb Q$ is not a linear continuum"

**My Attempt:**   I  think this statement is true.  Because $\mathbb R -\mathbb Q$ does not have  **Least Upper Bound Property**.

E.g. The set $\{\mathbb R -\mathbb Q \} \cap [2 , 3]$  is bounded in $\mathbb R -\mathbb Q $. But it does not have supremum.

Can anyone please check if I have gone wrong aywhere ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. If you wanted to be formal,  you'd need to prove why the supremum doesn't exist, but it's pretty obvious

Comment: @Sani. does my answer answer your question ?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to prove it has no irrational supremum you can show that given any irational  in $a$ in $[2,3]$  there is another irrational in between $3$ and a , for example $(a+3)/2$ so the least irrational upper bound must be greater than $3$ ,let that then be $n$ but then  $(n+3)/2$ is will be a lower  upper bound a contradiction hence no least upper bound exists.